# The order of the PriorityQueue is wrong

Tags: java, priority-queue

I meet a problem about order of PriorityQueue in Java 8, Intellij Idea, when  I add the third number in the queue, the order is wrong, but only the third one have this problem, here is my code.

```
import java.util.*;

public class vector {
    static Queue<Integer> q=new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
    public static void addNum(int num) {
        q.add(num);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        addNum(-1);
        addNum(-2);
        addNum(-3);
        addNum(-4);
        addNum(-5);
    }
}
```

I try to debug the code, after addNum(-3), the queue is -3,-1,-2, but after addNum(-4), the queue is -4, -3, -2, -1.

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "the queue is -3, -1, -2"? How are you observing that?

Comment: @JonSkeet I saw this behavior when doing a plain iteration of the PQ described in the OP's sample code.

Comment: Rough translation of the above comment (thanks Google Translate): You can only guarantee that the minimum value of each poll is because the data structure saved in it is not an array or a queue, but a binary small top heap. This addition and removal is the fastest.

Comment: Java uses implicit binary heaps stored in an array to implement PriorityQueue.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap for a complete description of how and why the tree maps into an array.  The array is ***not*** fully ordered, the only guarantee is that the minimum element is at the front.  The Wikipedia article has nice illustrations of exactly how this works.

Answer (score 12):

The contract for `PriorityQueue` does not guarantee *iteration* order, but rather it guarantees that each element *removed* from the priority queue will follow either the natural ordering of the queue's type, or the ordering of a custom comparator, should one be provided.

The [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) comments on what you are seeing:

> Queues typically, but do not necessarily, order elements in a FIFO (first-in-first-out) manner. Among the exceptions are priority queues, which order elements according to a supplied comparator, or the elements' natural ordering, and LIFO queues (or stacks) which order the elements LIFO (last-in-first-out).

The contract which Java appears to enforce for priority queues is that the first element *removed* from the queue will follow the natural order of the object in the queue, or using a custom comparator, should one be provided.

If we add to your current script to remove the five elements added, we will see that the items returned will be ordered from least to greatest:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    addNum(-1);
    addNum(-2);
    addNum(-3);
    addNum(-4);
    addNum(-5);

    // now remove all elements
    while (!q.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(q.remove());
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
-5
-4
-3
-2
-1
```

If you need a collection which maintains sorting order, then consider using something like `TreeSet`.  Or, you could use a regular `ArrayList`, and then call `Collections.sort()` if you want to impose a certain order.

Comment: I don't think you've explained the "I try to debug the code, after addNum(-3), the queue is -3,-1,-2" part... which I *think* is what's confusing the OP. (It's not a very clear question.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm updating now.

Answer (score 0):

PriorityQueue's implementation is a priority heap implementation & not sorted list.

The Iterator provided in method iterator() **is not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any specific order.** If you need ordered traversal, use something like:

```
Arrays.sort(q.toArray());
for (Integer data :q) {
  System.out.println(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As other answers implied, you should use `queue.poll()` if you want to retrieve the elements in the right order, as in:

```
    List<E> entities = new ArrayList<>();
    while(!queue.isEmpty()){
        entities.add(queue.poll());
    }
```

The order of entities in the `entities` list will be as expected.

Rationale: Java `PriorityQueue` only ensures the order of enqueuing of the entities, not the order of iteration in an underlying collection.

The entities are mapped onto an underlying collection "unsorted", meaning if you try to access the entities using a stream:

```
queue.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or an iterator:

```
Iterator<E> i = queue.iterator();
...
E e = i.next()
```

or any other method, such as `queue.forEach()`, or in fact observe your queue in a IDE debugger, there is no guarantee as to the order of the entries in the collections obtained using any of these methods.

Answer (score -2):

This the most Common Question, Many Collection Frame Work like ArrayList, LinkedList, and furthermore but In PriorityQueue, when you are printing the elements it will be in the Sorted Order and that order is followed **MIN_HEAP property** or
Basically, we can say that the ***Priority Queue is implemented on Min Heap Property.***
So First Understand the MinHeap then implement the code.