# Understanding how priorityqueue works

Tags: java

I have written the following while practising how priority queues work. While I think the output should be

```
Id: 5 Name: Apple
Id: 1 Name: Cat
Id: 2 Name: Dog
Id: 3 Name: Elephant


Id: 1 Name: Cat
Id: 2 Name: Dog
Id: 3 Name: Elephant
Id: 5 Name: Apple
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
Id: 5 Name: Apple
Id: 1 Name: Cat
Id: 2 Name: Dog
Id: 3 Name: Elephant


Id: 1 Name: Cat
Id: 2 Name: Dog
Id: 5 Name: Apple // <--= PROBLEM , it should be 3 not 5
Id: 3 Name: Elephant
```

The code is:

```
public class PriorityQueMYPRAC {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StudentNameSort nameSort = new StudentNameSort();
        StudentIdSort idSort = new StudentIdSort();

        PriorityQueue<Student> students1 = new PriorityQueue<Student>(nameSort);
        PriorityQueue<Student> students2 = new PriorityQueue<Student>(idSort);

        students1.offer(new Student(3, "Elephant"));
        students1.offer(new Student(2, "Dog"));
        students1.offer(new Student(5, "Apple"));
        students1.offer(new Student(1, "Cat"));

        for (Student student : students1) {
            System.out.println(student.toString());
        }

        System.out.println("\n");

        students2.offer(new Student(3, "Elephant"));
        students2.offer(new Student(2, "Dog"));
        students2.offer(new Student(5, "Apple"));
        students2.offer(new Student(1, "Cat"));

        for (Student student : students2) {
            System.out.println(student.toString());
        }

        System.out.println("DONE");
    }
}

class Student {
    int id;
    String name;

    public Student(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Id: " + this.id + " Name: " + this.name;
    }
}

class StudentNameSort implements Comparator<Student> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Student arg0, Student arg1) {
        return arg0.name.compareTo(arg1.name);
    }
}

class StudentIdSort implements Comparator<Student> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Student arg0, Student arg1) {
        if (arg0.id > arg1.id) {
            return 1;
        } else if (arg0.id < arg1.id) {
            return -1;
        } else
            return 0;
    }
```

Can someone please explain why I'm not getting the correct outputs.

I understand PriorityQueues doen't work like the Queues. The elements are processed based on the priority (natural order) or comparator. But it seems I'm missing something. Thanks for any help. :-) :-) :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56523319/the-order-of-the-priorityqueue-is-wrong

Comment: Where do you call `poll()`, remove()` or 'peek()'? Did you search on [Java priority queue not sorting](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+priority+queue+not+sorting+site:stackoverflow.com) before asking?

Comment: Wow, thanks.. I was stuck there for about 1hr. I made a note about it in my note-book. Now it is working. Thanks again